# Issue replacing values in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to copy an array, replace all values in the copy below a threshold but keep the original array in tact.

Here is a simplified example of what I need to do.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(0,1,.1)
B = A
B[B<.3] = np.nan
print ('A =', A) 
print ('B =', B)
```

Which yields

```
A = [ nan  nan  nan  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9]
B = [ nan  nan  nan  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9]
```

I can't understand why the values in A <= .3 are also overwritten?

Can someone explain this to me and suggest a work around?

Comment: `B = A` is not a copy.

Comment: `A` and `B` are pointing to the same object.

Comment: In general in Python references to objects rather than the objects themselves are copied if you use =, unless you use copy () (or even deepcopy () if the objects themselves hold references). This saves memory and time, but it's tricky at times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `B = A` to `B = A.copy()` and this should work as expected. As written, `B` and `A` refer to the same object in memory.